# Angular filter wont return a true value

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchBuddy" placeholder="search"  />
<div class="square">
  <div class="list no-padding" ng-repeat='buddy in buddyList | filter : search'>
    <a class="item item-avatar" href="#">
      <img src="{{buddy.photoURL}}">
      <h2>{{buddy.firstname}}</h2>
      <p>{{buddy.lastname}}</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>`
```

this is my HTML code

```
$scope.search = function (item) {
  if($scope.searchBuddy == undefined || $scope.searchBuddy == '' ) {
    return false;
  } else {
    if(item.firstname.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.searchBuddy.toLowerCase())!= -1) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

this is my controller code

In the example that I saw , if the input `searchbuddy` is empty, it will return `false` which causes the html `div` with `ng-repeat` to now show anything. Else if something is inputted and it somehow got something from `firstname`, it will return true and show the data which corresponds to the search input. But in my case it won't and I don't know why.

Comment: what you want, please explain more

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your 2nd if statement. You are referring to $scope.searchText when it should be $scope.searchBuddy as that is the model value you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use your ng-model with filter

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchBuddy" placeholder="search"/>
<div class="square">
  <div class="list no-padding" ng-repeat="buddy in buddyList |searchBuddy'>
    <a class="item item-avatar" href="#">
      <img src="{{buddy.photoURL}}">
      <h2>{{buddy.firstname}}</h2>
      <p>{{buddy.lastname}}</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(item.firstname.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.searchBuddy.toLowerCase())!= -1) {
      return true;
```

Comment: it still doesn't work sir .. i edited it and removed the if function leaving just the else{ return true;} but still does not return true ..